# Information about Olympia bicycles

Tags: mountain-bike

There is a bicycle dealer in my area selling "Olympia" bicycles. I haven't seen any athlete riding those bikes and I was unable to find any reviews on the internet. I know that the company is one of the oldest ones in Italy.
What I want to know is where do the Olympia bicycles stand in comparison with the other top brands like GIANT, Trek, BMC e.t.c.

Answer (score 3):

[Olympia](http://www.olympiacicli.it/en/company/who-we-are) bicycles are as good as any, and the company has been doing for about 100 years longer than any you mention.

Having said that Olympia produce good bikes, they have a different brand for pro-level equipment: [Scapin](http://www.scapin.com/en/history), one of which I am privileged to ride.

I gave an Olympia to my brother-in-law, three years ago. He's been riding it 500 km per month ever since without problems.